# Dynamically resizing views based based on NSOutlineView after expand/collapse animation

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'm using an NSOutlineView to display a hierarchy of tracks in a timeline, very similar to what would be seen in video editing packages. As the user expands/collapses items in the outline view, the corresponding objects in a scroll view alongside it appear and disappear.

Unfortunately, the `outlineViewItemDidCollapse:` and `outlineViewItemDidExpand:` delegate methods get called before the animation is complete, and calling `frameOfCellAtColumn:` on the outline view only gets the frame at that instant, while Cocoa is still animating its [dis]appearance.

As a workaround, I'm using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with a delay of 100ms (as is this [Dynamically resize NSWindow based on NSOutlineView height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952643/dynamically-resize-nswindow-based-on-nsoutlineview-height) person with a similar problem), but this isn't perfect (and it's smells bad). The animation isn't always finished inside 100ms, and any longer delay becomes quite noticeable.

```
-(void)outlineViewItemDidExpand:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // we need to delay the update to allow the outline view expand animation to
    // complete. Perhaps 0.1s isn't long enough in all cases, but any longer seems
    // too sluggish

    [self performSelector:@selector(updateSubviewsForTimeline:) withObject:timelineView afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

Is there any way I can hook into the `outlineViewDidExpand|Collase:` methods after the animation is complete? Alternatively, can I somehow get a handle on the animation itself inside my `outlineViewDidExpand|Collase:` methods so I can install a callback on that?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for that? I think I'm having the same problem when it comes to setting the column width in response to `outlineViewItemDidCollapse`. It probably doesn't work because Cocoa is still animating the appearance. See my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65186668/cant-change-column-width-in-response-to-outlineviewitemdidexpand

Comment: Never did, sorry