# Can't change column width in response to outlineViewItemDidExpand

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I want to update the column width to the width of the widest entry whenever a node in my `NSOutlineView` is expanded. Thus, my delegate listens to `outlineViewItemDidExpand` and calls

```
[column setWidth:maxColumnWidth];
```

in it. `maxColumnWidth` is the width of the widest entry.

However, for some reason, calling `setWidth` from inside `outlineViewItemDidExpand` doesn't seem to do anything. When I call it later, e.g. as a response to a button click, it works just fine, but from within `outlineViewItemDidExpand` it just does nothing.

So any idea what I could do to update the column width whenever the user clicks on an expander icon? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is `[column setWidth:maxColumnWidth]` executed and is the value of `maxColumnWidth` correct?

Comment: @Willeke: Sorry for not replying earlier. Other things have kept me busy. Of course I have verified that `setWidth` is executed and that the value of `maxColumnWidth` is correct. I have solved the issue now by calling `setWidth` using `performSelector` and a 0.0 delay. For some reason this solves the issue. Calling `setWidth` directly in `outlineViewItemDidExpand` didn't work but calling it from a selector called by `performSelector` from `outlineViewItemDidExpand` works. Weird. Unfortunately, I can't post this as an answer because the question has apparently been closed by someone.

Comment: I tried `[column setWidth:maxColumnWidth]` in `outlineViewItemDidExpand` and I dont' see any issues. Did you switch on the outline view's "Autoresizes" in IB or is `autoresizesOutlineColumn` `YES`?

Comment: I don't use IB but `autoresizesOutlineColumn` is indeed `YES` (which is also the default). I think the reason why `setWidth` doesn't work in `outlineViewItemDidExpand` is that `outlineViewItemDidExpand` is called while the UI animation shown by `NSOutlineView` hasn't completed yet. Using `performSelector` seems to work around that. Here's somebody who has seen a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807157/dynamically-resizing-views-based-based-on-nsoutlineview-after-expand-collapse-an ... he was also able to solve the issue by using `performSelector`.

Comment: `setWidth` doesn't work because if `autoresizesOutlineColumn` is switched on then the outline view resizes the outline column, apparently after `outlineViewItemDidExpand`.

Comment: Right, if I set `autoresizesOutlineColumn` to `NO` it indeed works correctly and `performSelector` is no longer necessary. Thanks a lot for the hint and please post this as an answer so that I can accept it because this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `autoresizesOutlineColumn` is `YES` (default) then the outline view resizes the outline column after `outlineViewItemDidExpand`. Solution: set `autoresizesOutlineColumn` to `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by calling `setWidth()` from a selector called by `performSelector()` from within `outlineViewItemDidExpand`, like so:

```
-(void) setColumnWidth
{
    [theColumn setWidth:...];
}

-(void) outlineViewItemDidExpand:(NSNotification*)notification
{     
    // calling setWidth() here doesn't work
    // [theColumn setWidth:...];
    
    // but calling setWidth() from a selector works!
    [self performSelector:@selector(setColumnWidth) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

Don't ask me why calling `setWidth()` only works from within a selector but it actually does...